# Array.push create 2 rows in the table using Angular 4

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, html-table

I've got 2 arrays that are the same except 2 items which are the 2 fakeDates:

```
 this.prodotti.push({ idAgreement: this.idAgreement,landingStatus: this.landingStatus, landingType: this.landingType, startDate: this.startDate, expirationDate: this.expirationDate, landingURL: this.landingURL, landingRequestURL: this.landingRequestURL, landingTaegMax: this.landingTaegMax, landingPF: this.landingPF });

 this.prodotti2.push({ idAgreement: this.idAgreement,fakeExpirationDate:this.fakeExpirationDate,fakeStartDate:this.fakeStartDate, landingStatus: this.landingStatus, landingType: this.landingType, startDate: this.startDate, expirationDate: this.expirationDate, landingURL: this.landingURL, landingRequestURL: this.landingRequestURL, landingTaegMax: this.landingTaegMax, landingPF: this.landingPF });
```

When I try to push them in my html table 2 rows are added instead of 1 even if in my code the binded array is `prodotti2`

Html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of prodotti2; let i = index">
            <td>
              <div class="celleProd">
                <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" style="text-align: center" value="{{row.landingType}}" id="sample3" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]+"
                  readonly="true">
              </div>
            </td>
```

So why does it create 2 rows each time I push the 2 arrays?

Comment: How are you invoking the `.push` code? Is that method getting called twice?

Comment: Is it possible that `prodotti` and `prodotti2` are _the same array_?

Comment: its getting called just once with the push of a button, and @IanMacDonald no the 2 arrays are different.
The weird thing is that im doing the same thing in another component and it works fine... im so confused :)

Comment: How are you instantiating them the two arrays? When it creates two rows, are they two identical rows, or is one row the row inserted into the first array and the second row the one inserted into the second array?

Comment: one row is from prodotti and one row is from prodotti2

Comment: Please show us how `prodotti` and `prodotti2` are declared and initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the console.log(prodotti2) to see if there is just one item on it, and when you are using *ngFor don't use id = sample3, is better if you use something like id= sample{{i}} ... sorry but i dont have reputation to make a comment ...